# How to use jq with popen to validate json data

Tags: c++, jq, popen

I am trying to use popen and jq on a Linux machine to validate json data in some unit tests but, for some reason, it does not work, i.e., jq's exit code is not zero. Here is a MWE:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
        std::string command = "echo {} | jq";
        FILE* pipe = popen(command.c_str(), "r");
        if (!pipe) return -1;
        char buffer[1024];
        std::stringstream ss;
        while(!feof(pipe)) if(fgets(buffer, 1024, pipe) != NULL) ss << buffer;
        int exitCode = WEXITSTATUS(pclose(pipe));
        printf("Exit code: %d\nOutput: %s\n", exitCode, ss.str().c_str());
}
```

However, if I replace 'jq' with (for example) 'head -1', the code works as expected. Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug in popen or jq?

Comment: I don't think you can popen a shell script

Comment: @AlanBirtles: AFAIK, jq is a binary not a shell script and the code works as intended if I replace "echo {} | jq" with "echo {} | head -1"

Comment: Try running `type jq` in your normal Terminal to see its full path. Then use that in your code.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: good guess but unfortunately the problem is not that jq is not found, jq is actually called and it writes its usage help message to stderr as if popen's command string had been `jq`. For some reason, the output of `echo` is not being piped into jq. Piping the output of `echo` into other commands works fine. Calling `echo {} | jq` in the terminal works fine too.

Comment: Have you tried starting a normal `sh` like `popen()` does, but by just typing `sh` in your Terminal. Then try `echo "{}" | jq` in that shell.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: I just tried what you suggested and that works fine too. I wonder if someone else is able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your code works fine on Ubuntu. Try changing your code to `which jq` and see if you get the same as in your shell. Try also `jq -V`

Comment: @MarkSetchell: thanks for your last comment. It helped me narrow down the problem. The code works for me too when I run it on Ubuntu 20.04, but not when I run it on two different docker containers based on Ubuntu 18.04. I'll try to narrow down the problem further

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 apt installs jq version 1.5-1-a5b5cbe. I compiled jq from source (version 1.6-145-ga9f97e9) and the MWE works fine. It was a bug in jq.